# Alt-tab with text filter in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, alt-tab

Is there a way to do an `alt-tab` type action but where you can quickly filter the list of open programs with a text search of the title?

For example, I have about 30-40 windows open and I know the one I want is titled **"default.build - Notepad2"**. So ideally I'd click `Alt-Tab` and then type **"defaul"** or **"Notepad2"** and it would filter the open list so I can quickly find it.

I use **UltraMon** to get a taskbar on each monitor, which is eternally useful but with three screens I sometimes forget which screen my app is on.

If there isn't such a thing then, damn it, I'll build one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like Switcher 2.0.0 will meet your needs. Out of the box it uses the shortcut LeftWinKey+` and will display a preview of all windows open on each monitor. Once the previews are up, you can start typing to filter the results displayed. It works pretty well with multiple monitors.

Switcher 2.0.0: http://insentient.net/Index.html

Personally, I tend to just use Win+TAB now to find the window I need.

Comment: What a great tool!! Win+TAB pales into insignificance when compared to Switcher! Thanks :)

Comment: @fletcher How did you find this? This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!!!